# Cannot set read-only property "errors" on object after ajax error

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

In order to show error messages from the server the following code is used :

```
    var onFail = function(result) {
        Ember.Logger.debug("ERROR CustomersCreateController");
        var json = result.responseJSON;
        Ember.Logger.debug(json['errors']);
        self.set("errors", json['errors']);
    };

    model.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
```

But when I have this response from the server  :

```
{"errors":[{"email":"O campo [email] precisa ser informado"}]};
```

An error is raised when I try to set("errors") ... any toughts ?
BTW I'm sending an 422 error from the server.

EDIT(1)
I saw this [post](http://yoranbrondsema.com/displaying-error-messages-ember-js-forms/) that skips the default errors feature, is this the only hope ? :)

EDIT(2)
Adapt the solution from EDIT(1) to use this, but Ember should have something easier !!!

```
    var onFail = function(result) {
        Ember.Logger.debug("ERROR CustomersCreateController");

        var json = result.responseJSON;
        self.set( "requestMessages", {});

        result.responseJSON["errors"].forEach(function(error_obj) {
            Ember.Logger.debug(error_obj.field + '='+ error_obj.message );
            self.set('requestMessages.' +error_obj.field, error_obj.message);
        });
    };
```

at the templates

```
    <div {{bind-attr class=":form-group requestMessages.name:has-error"}} >
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=name}} {{#if
            requestMessages.name}} <span class="help-block">{{requestMessages.name}}</span>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the response format should be:

`{"errors":{"email":["O campo [email] precisa ser informado"]}}`

Comment: Per property? You can return an array of error messages per property. You can the loop over error.email in your template. The errors object will be set on the Ember model